# Pandas groupby -- get output value based on max value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Habitat':['Jungle', 'Jungle',
                              'Sky', 'Sky'],
                   'Tmp':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

>>> df
   Animal Habitat Tmp  Max Speed
0  Falcon  Jungle   A      380.0
1  Falcon  Jungle   B      370.0
2  Parrot     Sky   C       24.0
3  Parrot     Sky   D       26.0
```

I am trying to add additional column "Output" which will take the value from "Tmp" based on maximum value of column "Max Speed" in a groupby done of columns "Animal" and "Habitat".

Desired output:

```
   Animal Habitat Tmp  Max Speed Output
0  Falcon  Jungle   A      380.0      A
1  Falcon  Jungle   B      370.0      A
2  Parrot     Sky   C       24.0      D
3  Parrot     Sky   D       26.0      D
```

It can be done using a `groupby` and then joining it in the original dataset. But is there a more efficient way to do this? Maybe using `transform` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function taking `pd.dataframe` as argument:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fmax(df_):
    df_['Output'] = df_.sort_values(['Max Speed']).tail(1)['Tmp'].squeeze()
    return df_
```

Please note use of `pandas.DataFrame.squeeze` function to return scalar value.
Then simply `apply` above function using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['Animal','Habitat']).apply(fmax)
```

The result is:

```
   Animal Habitat Tmp  Max Speed Output
0  Falcon  Jungle   A      380.0      A
1  Falcon  Jungle   B      370.0      A
2  Parrot     Sky   C       24.0      D
3  Parrot     Sky   D       26.0      D
```